# ASP.NET: how to set security of a file based on the app pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I created 2 ASP.NET applications.

WebApp1 is assigned to appPool1.

Webapp2 is assigned to appPool2.

WebApp1 should not access Data2.txt file.

Now I right click on Data2.txt, security tab . I was expecting to see something like appPool1(when I search for users) and deny access to this file under that.

But I cannot find it. I was thinking per app pool an actual user is created which is used by the worker process.

Please let me know how to deny WebApp1 access, Data2.txt(using appPool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to a file is managed by Windows ACLs, not by the app pool, directly. Each App Pool runs as a user, and you would assign the app pools different identities and restrict access to the file by the identities.

You can use a type of managed service account called [Application Pool Identities](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities), where the identity of the Application Pool is a special kind of identity that has the same name as the application pool. To grant/deny access to an application pool identity, you would use the name `IIS APPPOOL\AppPoolName` where AppPoolName is the name of your application pool. This will only work if the AppPool's identity is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity in IIS.

Comment: can you please clarify this part : "This will only work if the AppPool's identity is set to ApplicationPoolIdentity in IIS." How to do this?

Comment: Nver mind , ApplicationPoolIdentity is the default. Still im not clear. I search for "IIS APPPOOL\\DefaultAppPool" but this user cannot be found.

Comment: There should be only one slash, and the name of the app pool must be an exact match, including all white space. Also, if the server is domain joined, make sure "From this location" is set to the local machine, not the forrest.

Comment: same , search for object name "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool", An object named "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" cannot be found.

Comment: @SNash check that the "Location..." is set to the current name of the computer, not a domain.

Comment: Bravo!!! I Your are right . I changed location to local and it works.This was not so easy to guess!   you must be really good in ASP.Net!! If I could I would give you 100 +. Thanks a lot!!!